# In a UML notation context , the constructor of an abstract class returns what?

Tags: java, uml

For example , you'd put in the atributes field :

> - ClassTest() : ClassTest

in UML to represent the constructor, If it's an abstract class, does it works the same?

Comment: Or is it wrong in general to put in a UML that constructors return the class object?

Comment: Dear down voter trolls, please tell us why this has been down voted. The question is well formed and does not violate any SO rules.

Comment: Maybe everyone hates UMLs, I can sympathize...

Comment: You shouldn't work on academic level with UML unless you love it. Using it in practice is much more enjoying.

Answer (score 0):

It "would" return `self` but since it is abstract you can not instantiate it. So the question itself is rather pointless ;-)

Anyhow, your abstract constructor may very well do something meaningful once it is inherited somewhere. And in that case it would of course return the superclass.

Your question seems to be rather academic. Is there any real use case behind it?

Comment: It is academic yes, the context is constructing a UML chart and then implementing the code, with very specific rules. Its nothing advanced or thrilling really

Answer (score 0):

A constructor in Java is the method that is called to initialize an instance when it is created by the new operator. A Java constructor does not create a new instance, because an instance cannot create itself. A Java constructor does not return anything. The correct representation in a UML class diagram is therefore

```
ClassTest()
```

This is true for regular classes and abstract classes.